# How to use where condition in H2 database Table in grails

Tags: grails, persistence

What is equivalent statement for this query in grails.

```
select email from register where key="5"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `Register` is a domain class, here's how you'd do it with a criteria query.

```
def emails = Register.withCriteria {    
  eq 'key', 'S'

  projections {
    property 'email'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Register is a domain object:

```
Register.findByKey('5')?.email
```

Comment: It's unlikely to matter, but perhaps worth mentioning that the performance of this solution is sub-optimal because it will select all columns of the `register` table and then ignore everything except `email`. This is unlikely to make any significant difference, but something the reader should be aware of